# Is there a way to move files to directory in git repository?

Tags: git

I want to put my projects in one repository to see it clearly.
So I need to organize projects as directory.

For this, I made a directory in my repository and also cloned my projects in my repository.
So the result came out like a picture below.

'`dir`' is the name of directory that I want my projects to move.
And other files are projects files.

Question: I can move all files one by one by editing files?
There are many files in project so, I feel this way is inefficient.

Are there any ways to move files and folders of project at once in directory of repository?

**my repository**
[image]

**I want to organize like this**
[image]

Comment: Perhaps an easier way would be to do the folder structure changes locally? i.e. if you clone this repository to your computer, then make all necessary changes via either command line or a simple file explorer, then git commit your changes.

Comment: you mean, make new directory in local and move files to it then commit my changes right??

Comment: Doesn't `git mv` work for you?

Comment: @273K
Isn't `git mv` a name change, not a file transfer?

Comment: What do you mean by file transfer? Are you looking for rsync? BTW mv - is move, not rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to:

- clone the repository
- use a regular file explorer and move everything as you want
- `git add .` at the root folder of the repository: any move/rename will be detected then
- `git commit`  + `git push`